# loc and range in esprima

Tags: javascript, esprima

Esprima is a good library for parse, analyse for multi-purpose javascript code. But I am not understand `loc` and `range` in esprima. In the website, they said that:

- `loc` Nodes have line and column-based location info.
- `range` Nodes
  have an index-based location range (array)

I used example code to understand what it is.

```
var x = 42;
console.log(1);
```

And the result is :

```
"range": [
        0,
        27
    ],
```

Could you help me to understand `range` meaning.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Looks like string indices in the input text to me.

Comment: @Bergi You can view full AST tree in this [link](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=var%20x%20%3D%2042%3B%0Aconsole.log(1)%3B) and stick on Index-based range.

Comment: That page is broken for me. Try http://astexplorer.net/#/MrUNU1X4xg :-)

Comment: @Bergi, I think range is index character in code. For example: `var x = 42;` then range is `[0,11]`.

Comment: That's what I said. The code is the input text to esprima.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that Esprima loc and range isn't accurate for template nodes. It starts +1 from current index instead of 0. Just compare with either Acorn or Cherow and you see it yourself. Not sure for tagged templates.

Answer (score 0):

In the Esprima parse-result, range[0] is the (zero-based) index of the first parsed character. range[1] is the index of last parsed character + 1.

That convention makes it easy to use slice(range[0], range[1])
to get all of the text of a parsed element. But so just be aware that range[1] is NOT the index of the last parsed character but the index of the first character after that.

Esprima only produces the 'range' if you add the option {range: true} as  part of its 2nd optional argument.